# How to calculate the probability of no boats bumping into other?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

This is the hardest problem of Euler project: https://projecteuler.net/problem=597

Before start, please do not share any clue about the answer because this would be a spoiler to participants.

In the question, the case with 3 boats with 160 meters long river, the probability of no boats bumping into other is given as $\dfrac{4}{15}$.

I prepared a draft scheme to make it easier to understand:

[image]

However, I could not understand why. To my calculation, the condition of no boat bumping is:

$$\frac{80}{\vec{c}} \leq \frac{120}{\vec{b}} \leq \frac{160}{\vec{a}}.$$

How do we extract the given probabilty from this condition?

Comment: I don’t understand how you’re dividing by vectors. What does that mean?

Comment: Eventhough the direction of each boat is the same we need to be dividing the length by velocities. Pointing them as vectors may be unnecessary in this particular problem but they are in fact vectoral magnitudes.

Comment: In that case convention has that you should divide by the magnitudes, e.g. $\left\lvert\vec{c}\right\rvert$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Using the notation in the original description of the question, let $d = 40\text{m}$, $s = L - 2d = 80\text{m}$. Also, denote by $V_1, V_2, V_3$ the velocities of $C, B, A$, respectively.

The question says that the velocities of each boat are i.i.d as $V = -\ln X$, where $X \sim U(0, 1)$, thus $V \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$. Because the equivalent condition on which no bumps occurs is$$
\frac{s + 2d}{V_3} > \frac{s + d}{V_2} > \frac{s}{V_1},
$$
then probability of no bumps is\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-v_3} \,\d v_3 \int_{\frac{s + d}{s + 2d} v_3}^{+\infty}  \e^{-v_2} \,\d v_2 \int_{\frac{s}{s + d} v_2}^{+\infty} \e^{-v_1} \,\d v_1\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-v_3} \,\d v_3 \int_{\frac{s + d}{s + 2d} v_3}^{+\infty} \e^{-v_2} · \exp\left( -\frac{s}{s + d} v_2 \right) \,\d v_2\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-v_3} \,\d v_3 \int_{\frac{s + d}{s + 2d} v_3}^{+\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{2s + d}{s + d} v_2 \right) \,\d v_2\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-v_3} · \frac{s + d}{2s + d} \exp\left( -\frac{2s + d}{s + d} · \frac{s + d}{s + 2d} v_3 \right) \,\d v_3\\
&= \frac{s + d}{2s + d} \int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{3s + 3d}{s + 2d} \right) \,\d v_3\\
&= \frac{s + d}{2s + d} · \frac{s + 2d}{3s + 3d} = \frac{s + 2d}{3(2s + d)} = \frac{4}{15}.
\end{align*}

P.S.: The probability of no bumps with $n$ boats is

> $$\frac{2^n}{n!} · \frac{s (s + d) \cdots (s + (n - 1)d)}{2s (2s + d) \cdots (2s + (n - 1)d)}.$$